# ¿Cómo poner un loading después de hacer una consulta a Firebase en Angular 11?

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando haga una consulta a firebase aparezca un loading y desaparezca en cuanto obtenga los resultados.
Lo único que tengo es un método que hace q solo aparezca el loading y a los 3 segundos se desaparezca, pero no lo hace dependiendo si ya tiene los resultados de la consulta o no.

estoy usando ngx-spinner

ts

```
public nombre:string;
public resultados=[];

 buscar(){
    this.dbData.col$('COMENTARIOS', ref => this.query(ref));
    this.spinner(); //aqui llama el metodo spinner que es el LOADING 
   }

  async query(ref){

      let snapshot = await ref.where('nombre', '==', this.nombre).get();  //dependiendo de lo que escriba en la declaración nombre lo buscará
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       this.resultados.push(doc.data()); //aqui almaceno los resultados en un array  
      });}

 spinner():void{
    this.spinnerService.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.spinnerService.hide();
    }, 3000); //aqui le digo que se oculte a los 3 segundos, lo que intento es que se desaparezca cuando obtenga los resultados de la consulta
      }
```

html

```
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombre" > escribe el nombre a buscar

   <div class="card" *ngFor="let nombre of resultados;">
        
    {{nombre.cliente.nombre}}
            </div>
```

app.component.html

aqui solo es para personalizar el spinner, pero igual lo pongo

```
<ngx-spinner
bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.9)"
size="medium"
color="#fff"
type="ball-scale-multiple"
>
<p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Cargando resultados...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable global:

```js
loading = false

 buscar(){
    this.loading = true
    this.dbData.col$('COMENTARIOS', ref => this.query(ref));
    //this.spinner(); //aqui llama el metodo spinner que es el LOADING 
   }
```

Y cuando termine la ejecución de tu query la pones de nuevo en `false`

```js
async query(ref) {

  let snapshot = await ref.where('nombre', '==', this.nombre).get(); 
  this.loading = false //Aqui esta el truco.
//dependiendo de lo que escriba en la declaración nombre lo buscará
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    this.resultados.push(doc.data()); //aqui almaceno los resultados en un array 

    
  });
}
```

Simplemente llama, en el `html`, el spin cuando la variable este en `true`.